# Moto G5 Plus - will the US sim free version work with a UK sim card?

Tags: sim-card, motorola

I'm getting a new phone and I'm pretty set on the Motorola G5 Plus. I live in the UK but I will be traveling to the US soon and I'm considering buying a new phone while I'm there ($230 vs £250 here which is about a £50 difference even with MA sales tax).

Anyway - I am wondering if the G5 Plus from the US would work without any issues in the UK and the rest of Europe with a UK sim card. I googled around a bit and found some info on GSM bands but I hope that someone knowledgeable will be able to give me a definite answer.

This is what I found on Motorola's official website regarding this phone's bands:

> Moto G Plus - XT1687 CDMA (850, 850+,1900 MHz) GSM/GPRS/EDGE (850,
>   900, 1800, 1900 MHz) UMTS/HSPA+ (850, 900, 1700, 1900, 2100 MHz) 4G
>   LTE (B1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 12, 13, 17, 25, 26, 38, 41, 66)

I have also found bands supported by British carriers and they seem compatible to me but I would like to be sure first (it's also quite important that it works in the rest of Western Europe as I travel from time to time).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you have verified that the UK bands in use are included, I can't be more sure of compatibility than you already do...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it would not work on 4G as O2 in the UK requires band 20 which the US version of the phone XT1687 does not support.